# Prove group with restriction $b^{-1}a=ab$ is not abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

How do I prove that the group with restriction $b^{-1}a=ab$ is not abelian? (a and b not the identity)

If it is the case, I know $b=b^{-1}$ but I am not sure how that give a contradiction

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the group $\langle a,b | b^{-1}a=ba\rangle $?

Comment: I'm sorry I had a typo.  It's this group ⟨a,b| b−1a = ab⟩

Comment: Just adding the relation $ab=ba$ and trying to find a contradiction is not going to work: there *do* exist groups like that. The point here is that you have to show $ab\neq ba$ in this particular representation.

Comment: The presentation for the klein bottle's fundamental group that I was accustomed to is $\langle a,b | a^2b^2 \rangle$.

Comment: What I am trying to do is understand why the fundamental group of the klein bottle is not abelian.  The way I have it, the fundamental group of the klein bottle is the free group on two generators a and b modded out by that the least normal subgroup satisfying that relation.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, that one was for the projective space.

Comment: @slim well, you could do that by exhibiting two elements of the group that don't commute. That sounds doable, given a clear picture of the Klein bottle in your head... Otherwise you're basically trying to show that $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ is not in the smallest normal subgroup containing $a^{-1}bab$, and that doesn't sound like fun.

Answer (score 4):

The dihedral group of order $6$ (or indeed any other dihedral group) is a nonabelian homomorphic image of this group, so the group itself is non abelian.

Comment: A titanic improvement on "HNN extensions are non-abelian" :)

Comment: I recall doing something very similar in my topology class when we characterized the abelianization of the same group. My answer is similar but wordier, but it might illustrate the noobs way of working through it.

Answer (score 1):

The group $\langle a, b \mid b^{-1}a = ab\rangle$ is the HNN extension $\langle b \rangle *_{\varphi}$ where $\varphi: \langle b \rangle \to \langle b \rangle$ is given by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$. ($a$ is the stable letter.) It actually has a name: the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1, -1)$.

There's a theorem which states that an HNN extension $G *_{\phi}$ is abelian if and only if $\phi$ is the identity automorphism on $G$ where $G$ is itself abelian, which answers your question in an entirely unhelpful way.

There is a normal form theorem for HNN extensions, which basically says we can write any element as $$b^{n_0} a^{\pm 1} b^{n_1} a^{\pm 1} \dots b^{n_k}$$
uniquely in such a way that if any $n_i = 0$ then the preceding and following $\pm 1$ do not cancel each other out. This answers the question for us (under the right conditions, we can just concatenate two different normal forms to obtain another normal form, and the concatenations are different if we do them the other way round), though it's used some more high-powered theory than perhaps you'd like.

Comment: that is far too advanced for me to understand...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

Your group can be seen as follows: Let $F$ be the free group with generators $a$ and $b$.

Then the group that you want is $F/ \langle \langle b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a \rangle \rangle$

Now use the following property:

Suppose that you have a morfism $F\rightarrow G$ such that $\langle \langle b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a  \rangle \rangle$ is contained in the kernel. Then it induces a morfism $F/ \langle \langle b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a \rangle \rangle\rightarrow G$.

So all we need to do is find a surjective morfism from $F$ to a non-abelian group $G$ such that the kernel contains that subgroup, in other words such that $f(a)^{-1}f(b)^{-1}f(a)^{-1}f(b)=e$  ( since the kernel is a normal subgroup).

For instance, we can take the morfism $F\rightarrow S_3$ that sents $a$ to $(1,2,3)$ and $b$ to $(1,2)$